# Matching all words with a hashtag(#) in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Can anyone give me a quick way to extract all hashtags in a given sentence using shell scripts.

For example: 
`'This is a #test that will #allow me to #remove stuff'` would return `#test #allow #remove`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to try `egrep -o '#[^ ]+'`.  The output should look like:

```
#test
#allow
#remove
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to provide an alternative with awk:

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ /^#/) print $i}'
```

And here is pure BASH way of extracting these mathes:

```
x=$str # your original string
while :; do
   if [[ $x =~ (\#[a-z]+)(.*)$ ]]; then
      echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
      x="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
   else
      break
   fi
done
```